# Expand complex ansible variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have distinct ansible variables which are combined in a single command. More precisely, the system defines a variable with default value:

```
# This exists in an ansible variable definition file
instrumentor = ''
```

At some the python script that "creates" the ansible commands specifies the extra arguments to override the default values. I'm jumping through some hoops (using `\" and \'`) because the desired value contain spaces:

```
# This is a line from python script
instrumentation_specs = 
  '-e \'instrumentor=\"/software/cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck --log-file /tmp/memlog\"\''
```

On the ansible side then the command is structured as

```
;; This exists in a jinja template (.j2 extension)
;; command is what the start.yml script will be running
command="{{ instrumentor }}" my_program
```

Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. The command is reported to expand to something that contains extra `'` and `"`:

```
start.yml (...) -e 'instrumentor="/software/cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck --log-file /tmp/memlog"' (...)
```

The weird thing is that

- if I create another variable before command that only contains `instrumentor`, it is reported to have the exact value that I need

  ```
    instr_tmp = "{{ instrumentor }}"
    command = "{{ instr_tmp }}" my_program
  ```

  i.e. the extra `'` and `"` don't appear in `instr_tmp` but do appear in `command`
- If I ommit the `\" and \'` on the python side (when creating the string that is used to provide the extra arguments) everything that's after a space gets omitted.

Anyone knows how to specify such a variable override, i.e. how the string should look like when I specify a variable that contains multiple space separated strings (`instrumentor`), but that variable is supposed to be plugged into another ansible variable (`command`).

Comment: You tagged Python and YAML, but the code you're showing is neither. Semicolons for comments is something I have not seen in a long time. `a = "{{b}}" c` is not valid in Python, nor is it a YAML structure. Can you clarify which language you're using?

Comment: @flyx I mention in what sources each code lives, but to clarify further I added a comment on each to restate the source type, hope it helps, it's so frustrating trying to untangle this

Comment: It's still a bit confusing. By *ansible variable definition file*, you mean a `.fact` file with INI syntax? What kind of syntax does the `.j2` template produce? `command = "…" b` along with the semicolons still doesn't look like a familiar syntax after Jinja processing.